# When $f(x) = \begin{cases} -1, & \mbox{if } x<0 \\ 1, & \mbox{if } x>0 \end{cases}$ approaches 1 and -1

Tags: calculus, limits

In Spivak's calculus 3rd edition page 94 he says

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} -1, & \mbox{if } x<0 \\ 1, & \mbox{if } x>0 \end{cases}$$

if $a>0$ then $f$ approaches 1 near $a$ given $|x-a|<a$

if $b<0$ then $f$ approaches -1 near $b$ given $|x-b|<-b$

Where did he get $|x-a|<a$ and $|x-b|<-b$ from? Why not just say $x>0$ in the former case and $x<0$ in the latter? Moreover $|x-a|<a$ implies that $-a<x-a<a$ and $0<x<2a$, but if I choose $a=1$ and $x=500$, then it's not true that $x<2a$ but still $f$ approaches 1 at $x=500$ that is "near" $a$.

Comment: Recall the definition of continuity. For any $\epsilon>0$ you must find a $\delta>0$, such that
$$|x-a| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$$
The aurhor is implicitly saying that for $a>0$ you can choose $\delta = a$ and for $b<0$ you can choose $\delta = -b$.

Comment: Maybe they want to say that $f$ has a limit at any point $a>0$ (and this limit is $1$), and has a limit at any point $b<0$ (and that limit is $-1$)?

Comment: Did you mean to write $f(x)$ on the LHS?

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen continuity is a long way away from the limits chapter, but looks like it

Comment: @StinkingBishop they do, but they do it in a confusing way. That's why I asked where these expressions are coming from.

Comment: @super.t Well the limit definition is similar. For instance we can say for any $a>0$ that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$ is $1$ if and only if for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that
$$|x-a| < \delta \Rightarrow | f(x) - 1| < \epsilon$$
And again we see that $\delta = a$ works for any $\epsilon$.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen I should've read the chapter till the end first. Spivak is using a provisional definition where this bit missing, but he's using it in the examples which is confusing. Later in the formal definition he gives this implication.

Comment: $|x-a|<a$ ensures that $x$ is close enough to $a$ to be positive. These aren't the only $x$ that approach $1$, but that's ok. We're interested in the behavior of $f$ near $a$.